# Find Names of all the employees and the hours worked on each project ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database which includes an assignment table and an employee table. Each table includes employee id. Multiple employees work on the same project and I need to be able to get a list of the employee names for each project id and the hours worked. I tried the following but it does not work properly.

```
Select FirstName, LastName, ProjectID, HoursWorked
From employee e, assignment a
Where e.EmployeeNumber = a.EmployeeNumber
Group by projectID;
```

Edit: After the first answer I changed the query to this:

```
SELECT  FirstName, LastName, ProjectID, HoursWorked
FROM    employee e, assignment a
Where e.EmployeeNumber = a.EmployeeNumber
GROUP   BY ProjectID, FirstName, LastName;
```

And the results were fine, I don't fully understand the group by portion I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the *aggregate function* `SUM()` in order to get the total value of the column,

```
SELECT  FirstName, 
        LastName, 
        ProjectID, 
        SUM(HoursWorked) totalHoursWorked
FROM    employee e
        INNER JOIN assignment a
            ON e.EmployeeNumber = a.EmployeeNumber
GROUP   BY FirstName, LastName, ProjectID
```

Comment: Well, the hoursworked value is already a total actually. Your query worked, however simply adding the firstname and lastname to my group by returned the exact same thing... I don't understand why fully but I guess thats what I was missing.

Comment: [MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)

Comment: what is the formula you use to get `HoursWorked`?

Comment: Its just an attribute that already filled in the database already.

Comment: if `HoursWorked` is already a total then why don't you need `group by`? how is the result of this query `SELECT  FirstName, 
        LastName, 
        ProjectID, 
        HoursWorked
FROM    employee e
        INNER JOIN assignment a
            ON e.EmployeeNumber = a.EmployeeNumber` differs from with `GROUP BY`?